# How to Send current Textfield values through URL?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I want to send values of my textfields of JSP/HTML page through URL like this:

```html
<a href="some.jsp?uname=Somnath&dob=02/02/89&gender=male"></a>
```

But instead of static value I need to send the value which is putted currently.
Actually I want to receive the value of all fields by getParameter() method. But we can not use:

```html
<form action="someAnother.jsp" method="post">
```

Because there is anothere URL attached with the form.Actual Situation is:

```html
<form action="someAnother.jsp" method="post">
  <input type='text' name='uname'/>
  <input type='password' name='password'/>
  <input type='text' name='dob'/>
  <input type='text' name='contact'/>
  <a href="some">
    <input type='button' value='Upload Image'/>
  </a>
  <input type='submit' value='Register'/>
</form>
```

UploadImage Button call a servlet & make some operations and forward to this page again. And I need to fill all fields again which was filled by the user before hit the Upload Image Button.
So I think only way to get those values in that servlet is through URL.Please give me your suggestion.

- Remind that we can get all the field values in a JSP/Servlet only if we make the action through **form** tag & also remind the nested **form** is not allowed.
- So only way to call another servlet/jsp within a **form** tag again is **a** tag but it Carries no data with it.If i want to send some data with **a** tag then we have to use URL like firs Example.

Comment: Add upload button outside of form tag( before or after <form>) or use ajax

Comment: I use Javascript before but the problem is it's never get the full path of the image. Have you know any Example which can give the full path of a image not only the name.

Comment: you want to upload a file on server or just want a path ?

Comment: Both, Upload a file and give me the full path of source file. Can you send me a example code of this. It will be great help.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative 1:**

Change

```
method="post"
```

to

```
method="get"
```

**Alternative 2:**
Submit the above form data to a servlet (BasicInfoServlet). In this servlet, save the received data in session and the redirect/forward the user to image upload page. Submit the image upload form to a second servlet (ImageInfoServlet). In the second servlet write code to save/process the image and initial data from session.

Comment: I want to Receive all fields in "some" servlet not in "someAnother.jsp".

Comment: To receive all the fields in `some` servlet, specify the name of `some` servlet in the form's action attribute.

Comment: I mean change `<form action="someAnother.jsp" method="post">` to `<form action="someServlet" method="post">`. This will send all the parameters to the `someServlet`

Comment: In this page two action is required (1) For Registration (2) For Upload a File. Please read the question again.

Answer (score 0):

Use "get" method.

Code :-

```
<form action="/servleturl_mappingpath" method="get">
  <input type='text' name='uname'/>
  <input type='password' name='password'/>
  <input type='text' name='dob'/>
  <input type='text' name='contact'/>
  <a href="some">
    <input type='button' value='Upload Image'/>
  </a>
  <input type='submit' value='Register'/>
</form>
```

If you method is get, the requested data will be visible on URL.

When you click on Register Button, the request will go to the given servlet ( /servleturl_mappingpath) .

Now, you can get in servlet as below :

```
String namee=request.getParameter("uname"); 
String pass=request.getParameter("password"); 
String dobb=request.getParameter("dob"); 
String contactt=request.getParamenter("contact");
```

Use the above code in your servlet. And finally redirect your response to any given JSP.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I want to Receive all fields in "some" servlet not in "someAnother.jsp".

Comment: See the new posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use POST method and the enctype attribute of the form has to be set to "multipart/form-data"

**Check this post**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2424824/2106973

OR

**Tutorial for Java servlet upload file**
http://www.servletsuite.com/servlets/upload.htm